# Trigger another job if the existing build fails with timeout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, build-process

In Jenkins, I have used the [Build-time plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) to timeout and abort the build if the build takes more than a certain specified time. 
Is there a way to trigger another job immediately when this particular job fails with timeout where I can make my work process more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by installing the Parameterized Trigger Plugin on Jenkins.
(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)

Once installed, as a Post-build Action, add the `Trigger parametrized build on other projects`, from here you can select the Failure option that you need to trigger the next job.

[image]

Comment: sure. thank you. This looks like the one I need. I'll try this out.

Comment: i have a query, the above solution works if the job failed or unstable. but since my requirement here to trigger the next job **only if it fails with a timeout.** how can this be possible ?